# How to calculate rotation from 0 to 360?

Tags: expression, after-effects

I am trying to write an expression in After Effects, to display the degrees of rotation of an object. The problem is than, when the element is rotated counter clockwise, it doesn't start at `360` and than will count down to `0`. It will show me negative numbers from 0 to - negative infinite.

When rotate clockwise it will start from `0` and after it passed the `360` it will start over again from `0`.

How can I solve the counter clockwise rotation to the correct way?

```
x = Math.floor(thisComp.layer("Ellipse 2").transform.rotation)


if (x >= 0) x + "°"
if (x >= 360) x%360 + "°"
```

The code is applied to an text layer, that will display the correct degrees of the element "Ellipse 2".

Comment: `if (x < 0) x = x%360` might give you a positive x. Else `if (x < 0) x = x%360 + 360` This wil keep your x in the range [x, 360)

Comment: If I replace my if statements with yours, it doesn't solve the whole problem..

Comment: Don't replace them, add the statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to convert the value to positive to make sure you logic works

```
if (x<0)
   flag true;
x = Maths.abs(x)
if flag
    x = 360-x
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer now. Since 360 == 0 mod 360, you want an x in [0, 360).
The modulo operator might return a negative value if the argument is negative.
You'll have to test that for your programming language.

I'll assume, that `-1 % 5 == -1`, hence the modulo operator doesn't change sign. Then

```
x = Math.floor(thisComp.layer("Ellipse 2").transform.rotation)

if (x >= 0) x%360 + "°"
if (x < 0) x = x%360 + 360 + "°"
```

should do the trick.
If the modulo operator returns positive values, you can omit the "+ 360" in the last statement.

Comment: Thank you. This is working, but is there a possibility when rotating to the right, so +25° for example it will start by 360 and count back to zero. Instead of when the wheel is rotating clockwise, it starts by zero and will count up to 360?

Comment: The problem is there's no difference between 0 and 360 if you calculate mod 360. It'll be easy to display 360 instead of 0. But to choose between the two requires a strict definition. And especially in an initial situation where you don't know what's going to happen (rotate backward or forward), it'll be hard to decide which value to display. Basically you'd do `if (special-condition && x == 0) x = 360 + "°"` (and you remove the equals sign in the first if, which is OK anyway).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
r = thisComp.layer("Ellipse 2").transform.rotation;
x = r%360;
if (x<0) x+= 360;
Math.floor(x) + "°";
```